# Eclipse.app not opening on MacOSX, the executable opens terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've just finished reinstalling the latest Eclipse version with JDK 1.7 and all of my development tools.

However the install seems to be broken: double-clicking the Eclipse icon (the Eclipse.app package) does absolutely nothing!

However, these two options work:
1) going inside the package in the Contents/MacOS/ folder and double-clicking the "eclipse" UNIX executable file
2) double clicking an "eclipse" named shortcut file located in the same folder ad the Eclipse.app package; the shortcut actually links to the executable from number 1)

When either of these two launch, they open a terminal and run the executable at 1) with full path, then the exit command. The terminal stays open though, and if I attempt to close it, it closes Eclipse (first warns me about closing Eclipse processes).

Any ideas on how to fix this, besides doing a full reinstall (which I already did)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problems in the past.
Mostly it was the lack of correct execution rights of the executable file.
Try this in the package contents under Contents/MacOS/Eclipse:

```
chmod +x eclipse
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem some days ago and I solved it today.

Just installed this

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572

And after that when I opened the eclipse the mac os installed some java update and opening eclipse by Eclipse.app started working.

Hope it works with you too.